# Async input not updated Angular2

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I'm trying to retrieve some data in a parent component and use it in a child component. But changes are not detected (ngOnChanges is not fired).

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  countries: VisitedCountries;
  @ViewChild('childModalComponent')
  childModalComponent: ChildModalComponent;


  openChildModal() {
    this.childModalComponent.openModal();
  }

  displayProfil() {
    var that = this;

   // If I put this here, child component has an updated variable => ngOnChanges is fired
   // this.countries = new VisitedCountries(...)

    this.userService.getUserProfil()
      .then(result => {
            // this.countries is not updated in child component
            that.countries = new VisitedCountries(result) as VisitedCountries;

      });
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<span (click)="openChildModal()">
<child-modal [countries]="countries"> </child-modal>
```

**UPDATED**

**childModal.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-modal',
  templateUrl: './childModal.component.html'
})
export class ChildModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input()
  countries: VisitedCountries;
  selectedCountries: Country[];

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   // not fired with async content
  }

  openModal() {
    this.selectedCountries = [];

    // simplified algo
    for (country in this.countries) {
      this.selectedCountries.push(country); 
    }

    // this.selectedCountries is well filled at this point
  }

}
```

**childModal.component.html**

```
<modal>
  ...
    // primeng autocomplete
    <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" [suggestions]="filteredCountriesMultiple" field="label" (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)"
        [multiple]="true">
    </p-autoComplete>

 ...
</modal>
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  getUserProfil(userId: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as User)
      .catch(error => {
        return error;
      }
      );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I use zone.run() it works (but I still don't know why I have to do this)

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  function () {
    this.zone.run(() => this.displayProfil());
  }
}
```

and

**childModal.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-modal',
  templateUrl: './childModal.component.html'
})
export class ChildModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input()
  countries: VisitedCountries;
  selectedCountries: Country[];

  openModal() {
    this.selectedCountries = [];
    this.zone.run(() => {
      // I had another async call here
      service.getObject().then (() => {
        for (country in this.countries) {
          this.selectedCountries.push(country); 
        }
      });
    }); 

   // or this.ref.detectChanges(); also works  
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Check `Zone.current.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering change detection manually

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'

export class ParentComponent {

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ...

this.userService.getUserProfil()
  .then(result => {
        // this.countries is not updated in child component
        that.countries = new VisitedCountries(result) as VisitedCountries;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: What did I break in my code that force me to detect some changes manually ? I tried to add this line "this.cdr.detectChanges();" before. ngOnChanges is fired in the child component, but view is not updated with the correct value

Comment: @isy can you include the view too then?

Comment: @isy where do you call  `openModal()` ?  Your `selectedCountries` is empty until that point

Comment: openModal is called from the parent with 'openChildModal' when user clicks on an edit button to display a modal (i've updated my code again).

Comment: @isy ok what do you expect to see inside the view?

Comment: A list of countries retrieved from the server (stored in this.countries and added to this.selectedCountries). I expect to see some label coutries in an input (p-autoComplete from ngserve)

Comment: @isy I didn't quite understand that.Your child components ngOnChanges now gets updated right? Which is your question.. This has been solved. Now you are asking that everything is ok but the lib that you are using is not working?

Comment: Ok I accept you answer, in fact I don't suspect primeng lib. I'm affraid I have to trigger change detection manually everywhere to display my countries, because angular can't detect changes itself (I don't understand why)

Comment: @isy Probably you didn't provide enough information and maybe your callback is called outside angular zone

Comment: @isy No no, I didn't say that to you to accept my answer, I can delete my answer if you like. It's just a little unclear to me.

Comment: @yurzui Your hypothesis interests me, what could be the possible reason ? (callback called outside angular zone) So that I can continue my research. I've added my service above if it can help.